# How can write snippet with arguments to extent?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I have write an small snippet for `html-table` to extend when editing `rst` file:

```
vim .vim/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips/rst.snippets

snippet html-table  "put html" i
.. raw:: html

   <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
              write text
          </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
endsnippet
```

Typing `html-table` can extend as i expect when editing `rst` file,

```
.. raw:: html

   <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
              write text
          </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

now i want it more smart,add two arguments:one for row ,another for column,how can extend `html-table(n,m)` as  n rows and m columns?

Comment: What does the plugin documentation say about that?